# Do multiple logical statement work in a single while loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to design a game of tic-tac-toe on python. I was just trying it out step by step before arranging the whole program. But I am stuck with the conditioning part of it. Specifically the while loop. Previously, I've only used a single logical/boolean expression. Here I need to use multiple ones.

I have tried it for just the horizontal conditioning as of now, but still it doesn't work.

```py
finaltic=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def tic_board():
    print(finaltic[0],'|',finaltic[1],'|',finaltic[2])
    print(finaltic[3],'|',finaltic[4],'|',finaltic[5])
    print(finaltic[6],'|',finaltic[7],'|',finaltic[8])
tic_board()

def replace_tic():
    a=int(input('Enter your number: '))
    z=a-1
    finaltic[z]='X'
    tic_board()
    b=int(input('Enter your number: '))
    x=b-1
    finaltic[x]='O'
    tic_board()

def conditional_tic():
    con1=finaltic[0]!=finaltic[1] or finaltic[1]!=finaltic[2]
    con2=finaltic[3]!=finaltic[4] or finaltic[4]!=finaltic[5]
    con3=finaltic[6]!=finaltic[7] or finaltic[7]!=finaltic[8]
    while con1 and con2 and con3:
        replace_tic()
conditional_tic()
```

As soon as anyone of the variables i.e. con1 or con2 or con3 become False, the while loop should break. But it goes in infinite loop.

Comment: you need to update con1, con2 and con3 inside the loop as well for their values to change to reflect the desired result.

Comment: @ruhaib When I passed in just the condition of con1 in the while loop, it worked perfectly fine. That means the values of finaltic[0:3] were getting updated. But as soon as I replicated it for finaltic[3:9], the while loop went to infinity mode.

Comment: You are right that values of finaltic are being updated. But, the con1 was calculated on a previous value of finaltic and it needs to be calculated again on the new finaltic values. which is why you need to call the same code of calculating your cons inside the while loop after calling **replace_tic()**

Answer (score 0):

For your loop to work, you'll need to recompute the conditions inside of it. Currently, `con1`, `con2` and `con3` are only computed once, and then their values are tested repeatedly. That's probably not very useful, since they'll always have the same values (even if `finaltic` changes).

You could fix this by copying the whole set of the computations to the bottom of loop:

```
con1=finaltic[0]!=finaltic[1] or finaltic[1]!=finaltic[2]
con2=finaltic[3]!=finaltic[4] or finaltic[4]!=finaltic[5]
con3=finaltic[6]!=finaltic[7] or finaltic[7]!=finaltic[8]
while con1 and con2 and con3:
    replace_tic()
    con1=finaltic[0]!=finaltic[1] or finaltic[1]!=finaltic[2]
    con2=finaltic[3]!=finaltic[4] or finaltic[4]!=finaltic[5]
    con3=finaltic[6]!=finaltic[7] or finaltic[7]!=finaltic[8]
```

But copying and pasting code like that is usually a bad idea (both because it can copy bugs, but also because you might want to update the condition later and after a copy/paste you'd need to update two places consistently).

A better solution might be to avoid the extra variables and just do the `or` tests directly in the `while` condition. Alas this does require extra parentheses, since the condition is quite long:

```
while (  # these outer parentheses are only needed to let us split over multiple lines
    (finaltic[0] != finaltic[1] or finaltic[1] != finaltic[2]) and
    (finaltic[3] != finaltic[4] or finaltic[4] != finaltic[5]) and
    (finaltic[6] != finaltic[7] or finaltic[7] != finaltic[8])
):
    replace_tic()
```

You might also consider writing a function to do the condition testing, and call it from the loop condition. That's only a definite win if you might need that condition elsewhere.

Comment: I tried your alterations but it didn't work. The function worked right for 2 iterations and then stopped working with 'In[*]'. I had to interrupt and restart the kernel. Any idea as to why its happening ? Because the reason you gave for my previous code not working was absolutely right. I forgot to update the True/False values of the logical statements inside the while loop.